# NoMethodError on section 5.7 of Rails Guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Getting Started tutorial for Rails 4.0.0 located here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I'm at the point in section 5.7 where I'm supposed to be getting the ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes error. Instead, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show

Showing C:/Rails/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #8):
5
6  <p>
7    <strong>Text:</strong>
8    <%= @post.text %>
9 </p>
```

Despite this, I believe the posts are being created, since the ids are being incremented each time I submit the form. I am brand new to Rails, and have attempted to exactly follow the instructions.

I'm running Windows 7 x64, with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.0.

Here are some relevant files; please let me know if any other are required.

#### posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

#### show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>
```

#### new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Post</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write down `show` method after `create` method, as your show method is below the keyword `private` it is taking private as a `Access Modifier` and hence can't access directly through browser

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)    
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end           
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stuck on that for a while.

Comment: Pro tip would bo to not put protected/private keyword loose in class but for concerned method add (underneath) `private :post_params`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the tutorial (which at this date (11/18/14) uses 'articles' instead of 'posts'), and found the solution to be the placement of the following "def" block in articles_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Here's what it looks like for me:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def new
    end

def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

private
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end 
end
```