# Getting Started with Rails Tutorial 5.7: Article object is not being created correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails: 4.1.2
Ruby: 2.1.2

I'm trying to complete the Getting Started tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) but am having trouble with section 5.7.  At the point when my Title and Text should both be displaying correctly, I am getting an "unknown attribute: title".  My suspicion is that the article object is not being created or saved correctly, but I haven't been able to find the bug.

Here is my articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    # render plain: params[:article].inspect
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end


  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end

  private :article_params
end
```

My show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>
```

And my rake routes:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

Also something that may be of interest are the parameters as reported by the error page, they didn't look as I would have expected, but what do I know?

**Parameters:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"OFbPxhf...2V+e9zu3A=",
 "article"=>{"title"=>"sdf",
 "text"=>"sadfdf"},
 "commit"=>"Save Article"}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?  Thanks!!

Comment: can you post your error and model also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this, from your comment, `#<Article id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"` the problem is that when you created your Article model, you didn't add the title and text columns. Try this:

```
rails g migration add_title_to_articles title:string text:text
rake db:migrate
```

That should add a title attribute to your articles model and you should be good to go.

After reading section 5.4 of the guide, I suspect that you forgot a little part of the generate model command and are missing those fields. Instead of this:

```
rails generate model Article title:string text:text
```

You may have done this:

```
rails generate model Article
```

This would have generated just an :id, :created_at, and :updated_at

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-article-model

Answer (score 1):

This should be

```
private
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

and remove this line `private :article_params` and try once

Comment: Tried but it didn't help, I had used that syntax after reading the last comment on this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464370/nomethoderror-on-section-5-7-of-rails-guide

Comment: @user1742386 Add `@article = Article.new` in `new` method and try once

Comment: @user1742386 You should be adding `@article = Article.new` in the `new` method and follow anusha's answer.

Comment: Tried that as per another SO thread, but now when I load the initial form I get the following error: "undefined method `title' for #<Article id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"

Comment: @user1742386 Can you post your form, model and statck trace error once

Comment: @user1742386 Do you actually have a `title` attribute in your `articles` table?