# The view only displays Title: and Text: but does not seem to fetch data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie on RoR. I am following [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and am stuck at Sec 5.7.

I have this as the articles_controller.rb

```
 class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def new
   # @article=Article.new
    end
def create 
    @article = Article.new(params[:article_params])
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
    end
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
private 
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

end

This is my show.html.erb-

```
<p>
 <strong>Title:</strong>
 <%= @article.title %>
 </p>

 <p>
 <strong>Text:</strong>
 <%= @article.text %>
 </p>
```

when I run the `http://localhost:3000/articles/new` the form is displayed, entering some Title and some text I click on submit button, the next page has the url: `http://localhost:3000/articles/1` or 2(some id). It displays

```
Title:
Text:
```

but no value is displayed to the right. I tried other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073721/getting-started-with-rails-tutorial-5-7-article-object-is-not-being-created-cor), but it didn't help.

Following some SO thread, I also tried replacing  `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` by   `@article = Article.find(params[article_params])` in the show action definition of the controller, but it gives some error--

`param is missing or the value is empty: article`

error is around this line

`params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)`

Comment: can you check that the article is being saved in db or is it validated ?

Comment: Try by changing this line `@article = Article.new(params[:article_params])` to `@article = Article.new(:article_params)

Comment: Uncomment the new action, so take away the #. Also on the create action, change to this: @article = Article.new(article_params)

Comment: @Suomi: It is working now with the steps you mentioned. Make it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Well, if you want to use `article_params` and have `id` as params, you will have to change this `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)` to `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :id)`. And it should work for you :)

Comment: Great that it works, @Learner! I made it an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the new action, so take away the #. Also on the create action, change to this: @article = Article.new(article_params)

Answer (score 2):

Use `@article = Article.new(article_params)` instead of `@article = Article.new(params[:article_params])`

Comment: This gives `When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.` error

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def new
    @article=Article.new
 end
def create 
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
end
```